# Modificar cursor do VIM rodando no Console2

Tags: console, terminal, vim

Não consigo mudar o tipo de cursor do VIM quando entro no modo Insert, quando utilizo o Console2.

Queria que ele fizesse como faz no cmd, conforme a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe se é possível, e, se for possível, como se faz?

Comment: Não é uma resposta à pergunta, mas já achei uma [versão modificada do Console2](https://github.com/cbucher/console) que me atendeu.

Comment: No settings do programa, tem que selecionar o cursor para o tipo Console.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

No geral em vim mostrar o modo está ligado a

```
:set showmode
```

Para ver detalhes

```
:help showmode
```

pode ser definido no ficheiro de configuração ($HOME/.vimrc em unix, $HOME/_vimrc em windows)